# Ubuntu most menu items dark-on-dark

Tags: linux, gnome, ubuntu-10.04, themes

Since to ubuntu 10.04 upgrade move of my drop-down menus have been dark-on-dark text, which becomes readable (changed background) when selected. I don't know what's causing this but it's a problem on Ambience and Radiance both. Any hints?

Comment: Did you look for errors in the installation? Do you have any special settings for text that may not be playing nicely with the new themes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a problem with the theme files, it is probably specifying dark text on the dark background. Try to change to another (light) theme and look if the dark text is there, and try to change back again.

Comment: Ambience and Radiance are the new themes for 10.04, they're not going to be specifying dark-on-dark.